# Deforming a rectangular image into an irregular shape

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I've been looking around the net on how to deform regular shaped to irregular shapes. So far i have only found resources regarding making things follow a curved path or simmilar.

I am looking to do a full shape transformation. Turning a regular rectangle into a irregular shape, efficiently. My ideal goal is to use this for simple 2D cloth simulation animation.
[image: Shapes]

Are there any existing resources on the web that i have not managed to find? Or do any of you know how i would go about creating an algorithm to deal with this type of deformation.

My initial guess would be to deform my shape sequentially axis by axis, but i fear this may lead to a lot of distortion. Any ideas?

Comment: I think i may have found out how to do something similar to what i wish to achieve using AfflineTransform and shear(). Its still will not quite achieve the full effect however.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html

Comment: You should probably point out whether you really want to apply this to an *image* - particularly, are you talking about a `BufferedImage`? In how far is this related to cloth simulation? For such a simulation, you will usually need 3D coordinates, otherwise the distances (edge lengths) do hardly make sense (in 2D, you could only sensibly simulate a *rope* - that is, 1D object). Regardless of that: The problem with AffineTransforms (even in 3D) is that they are ... well, *affine*. They don't offer arbitrary transformations. Some more info about the background and intentions may be helpful here

Comment: Sure, basically, this. http://puu.sh/8r7bz.PNG Except all lines would be straight, rather then the small curves. This will be used for cloth clothes on my game characters. And yes, it would be a series of BufferedImages. Edit: in theory affine transformation would be most realistic in this application, as the material would not be made to stretch.

Comment: Actually, what you showed is not an affine transform it's a perspective transform. An affine transformation keeps parallel lines parallel. If it helps, OpenCV has some built-in functionality for performing perspective warps.

Comment: @LexWebb About the linked image: When the cloth is attached at two corners, and the edges may **not** stretch at all, then ... it will remain the perfect rectangle as in the left image! Apart from that, such simulations usually do not work with the deformation of quadrilaterals. Usually, they operate on the edges, which (in the simplest case) are modeled as forces of a mass-spring model ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_body_dynamics#Cloth_simulation ). Rarely, these methods operate on triangles, for anisotropic stretching behavior. In any case, the simulation is in no way related to images

Comment: Oh I know,  if it comes to me texturing my cloth.  This is how I thought I would go about it.  In any case,  I'll give it all a go once I've built my physics model and we'll see,

Comment: @rogerrowland thanks,  I'll have a look into that

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it by breaking the image up into rectangles (and then each rectangle into two triangles) and then using `graphics.drawImage(..)` after setting an `AffineTransform` to the graphics (which is a different transform for each triangle).

I've done it in this applet: http://nik-sergeev.com/trees.html

(If you click through the various warnings about Java applets that come up nowadays), then what you will see when you click on pages or bookmarks in the applet is a "page turning" effect, which is done as described above. (It's an applet that is supposed to look like a book.)

Any mapping that is locally affine can be achieved this way. (Which is most of the ones you would ever care about.)

To find the six parameters that define the `AffineTransform` for each triangle, you have to ray-trace for the three corners of each triangle. (If you're not familiar with "ray tracing", it's much easier than it sounds. You just have to specify where the point maps from and where it maps to.) Then solve for the affine transform parameters using some basic maths.